# How to handle media queries in HTML emails in Gmail?

Tags: html, email, gmail, media-queries, inbox

I send responsive HTML emails with my website, with media queries, but in Gmail / Inbox, `max-width` in the media query refers to the browser viewport, instead of the HTML email.

So, on every other mail client, my emails switch to mobile display under 600px, in Gmail / Inbox, this comportement is broken.

Do you have a solution to make the media query take as viewport the mail viewport instead of the browser viewport ?

Comment: did you set the `meta viewport` in mail HTML?

Comment: Yes : `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: what about `width=device-width` ?

Comment: Already tried, nothing changed :/

Comment: Last test was : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> `

Comment: can you share the code you tried and screenshot of working in both gmail and someother mail(where it works good)

Comment: Pastebin : https://pastebin.com/xYUN0dYD

Comment: DId it work fine on outlook?

Comment: No, the mail looks disgusting, but it's because Outlook use MS Word html render engine

Comment: In which mail it works perfectly

Comment: Gmail/Inbox on mobile app

Comment: This is what I see when resizing the window in outlook online https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6PAF.png

Comment: It's correct display, but try to resize smaller

Comment: It is resized to half of the screen already

Comment: So, it seems like ok in Outlook. But in Gmail, it is ugly

Comment: http://recordit.co/Fid1PpjE5m

Comment: For me, the problem isn't happening. It looks fine in Outlook

Comment: But not in Gmail ^^ (see the video)

Answer (score 3):

1. Recommended approach: `<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`
2. Avoid `minimum-scale`, `maximum-scale`, `user-scalable`.

Comment: I'll try it monday !

Comment: Not working :/ The problem is the browser handles the media query with browser width, and not the "mail view" width ... A normal comportement, I guess, but can't work properly in webmails